# Python Can not parse website Human problem but open in website

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, parsing

i try to parse website but there is error
`You need to enable support for <a href="https://yandex.ru/support/common/browsers-settings/browsers-java-js-settings.html">js</a> in your browser to visit this site`

I try this code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://siteurl"
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(URL.strip(), headers=headers, timeout=100)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.contents)
```

when i try to open in browser , it's work .
Any solution?

Comment: That response is not an error.  The website returned that content because it knows that you are using a method that does not understand javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The website asks for the enabled JavaScript. BeatifulSoup does not mimick a full-fledged web-browser, so it lacks JavaScript functionality. You can try using Selenium + BeatifulSoup together since Selenium behaves as a full fledged browser.

Answer (score -2):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://siteurl"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Comment: not working , same problem

Comment: This is nearly identical to the code that the questioner already tried.  How is it supposed to solve the problem?